# Replacing VW 6 CD Changer with an AUX port

Tags: vw, golf, audio, electronics

I have a 6-CD CD Changer (Same as this one [1DINCDC](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/VW-GOLF-MK5-6-DISC-CD-CHANGER-1K0035110-/262372402370)) in my MK5 Golf (04 reg) which lives in the armrest compartment. Is it possible to install an AUX port/cable to replace the CD changer somehow?

The car is also fitted with the stock stereo. I don't mind losing the CD changer's functionality in favour for an AUX port, as long as the radio/stereo remain to work fine.

Comment: Do you still want the stereo to work the changer? My bet is, you can re-route to the AUX, but you'll lose the functionality of controlling the changer ... it may become strictly an audio output and lose functionality. Do you have the stock stereo in your Golf? Can you give us a little more detail about your end goals and the current setup? I had an '04 Jetta with the stock stereo and added the changer later. I wouldn't think I'd have been able to add the changer into the stock stereo off of an AUX connection, nor would I have wanted to. It seemed to work very well as designed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the changer style you posted, but the head unit info would be a great add.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes I do have the stock stereo. I don't really mind losing the CD changer all together, as long as I get a functioning AUX port/cable out of it, and as long as the stereo's functionality is not effected (radio etc.)

Comment: Let me get it straight then, you're just looking to remove the CD Changer and convert it to an AUX port where the CD Changer currently connects? That's interesting, but a question I cannot answer. If that is the case, can you add those details into your question? I'm interested to see if there is a way to do it :o) Could be very pertinent to others.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 didn't realise how confusing the wording was till you pointed it out haha. Updated now, thanks!

Comment: I don't think you'd have an issue with losing the stereo, but I think you'd have to have some kind of adapter to get the changer connection to work as an AUX input. Fake the radio into thinking it's still connected to the changer, when in fact it's connected to an iPod/Phone/Pad or some other USB enabled device.'

Comment: VW made iPod adapters which plugged in I place of the CD changer.

Answer (score 1):

If your radio is the [RCD 300](http://www.michaelneuhaus.de/golf5/pic/rcd300_neu.jpg) you can fit an **aux adapter**.

There are two types of aux adapters:

**Analog adapters** - those are basically just a cable with a 3,5mm plug or a socket. Some of the socket versions can be fitted into your dashboard.

**mp3 adapters** - these adapters are designed to replace your original CD changer and use an usb stick or an SD card to play mp3 files. The adapter acts like a CD changer, you can control it directly from the radio.

You can get both types from eBay or other stores. The analog type is probably cheaper. 
Just google for "**RCD 300 aux**".

Both versions require your radio to be removed for installation, AS the cable needs to be plugged into the back of the radio. However, this is a simple procedure and there are tutorials available how to do it.

Image source: MichaelNeuhaus.de